# Google Sheets - how to insert row(s) into multiple tabs within same sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet with 20+ tabs.

Is it possible to perform the "Insert -> Row Above" command on multiple tabs?

I know it can be done in Excel (Group Tabs, Insert, Ungroup), but I don't see any way to group tabs in Sheets.

I can do it manually, i.e. Insert->Row Above, click next tab, Insert->Row Above, click next tab, etc - but that's tedious, annoying, and error-prone.

So, is there a command to insert row and replicate that action across all tabs in a sheet? Or is it possible to write a script for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no "group tabs" in Google Sheets. The following script provides a function to insert a row above the current position in all sheets of the current spreadsheet.

```
function insertRow() {
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  var row = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getRow();
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    sheets[i].insertRowBefore(row);
  }
}

function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu("Custom", [{name: "Insert row above everywhere",  functionName: "insertRow"}]);
}
```

Specifically, `insertRow` is the function that performs insertion, and `onOpen` is to add a corresponding menu item to the spreadsheet (invoked automatically when the spreadsheet is opened in a browser).

Comment: Works 100%, thank you SO much!

The only issue is that it doesn't always seem to update, unless you manually reload the sheet, but that could be due to the size & complexity & the number of IMPORTRANGE functions in the sheet.

I'll just bear it in mind, and add rows where needed, then reload, then enter new data. Thank you again!

Comment: How do I use this? Where in sheets do I go to execute it, I mean?